# How work pre-defined descriptors in functions?

Tags: python, function, metaprogramming, descriptor

Python functions have a descriptors. I believe that in most cases I shouldn't use this directly but I want to know how works this feature? I tried a couple of manipulations with such an objects:

1. ```
   def a():
       return 'x' 

   a.__get__.__doc__
   'descr.__get__(obj[, type]) -> value'
   ```

   What is the obj and what is the type?
2. ```
   >>> a.__get__()
   TypeError:  expected at least 1 arguments, got 0

   >>> a.__get__('s')
   <bound method ?.a of 's'>

   >>> a.__get__('s')()
   TypeError: a() takes no arguments (1 given)
   ```

   Sure that I can't do this trick with functions which take no arguments. Is it required just only to call functions with arguments?
3. ```
   >>> def d(arg1, arg2, arg3):
           return arg1, arg2, arg3
   >>> d.__get__('s')('x', 'a')
   ('s', 'x', 'a')
   ```

   Why the first argument taken directly by `__get__`, and everything else by returned object?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`a.__get__` is a way to *bind* a function to an object. Thus:

```
class C(object):
    pass

def a(s):
    return 12

a = a.__get__(C)
```

is the rough equivalent of

```
class C(object):
    def a(self):
        return 12
```

(Though it's not a good idea to do it this way. For one thing, `C` won't know that it has a bound method called `a`, which you can confirm by doing `dir(C)`. Basically, the `__get__` does just one part of the process of binding).

That's why you can't do this for a function that takes no arguments- it must take that first argument (traditionally `self`) that passes the specific instance.

Comment: `a.__get__(C)` is like `C.a`, not `C().a` as in your second example.